# How to center text using Three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, three.js

I'm trying to render text like the one in the picture. I can manually put line break to the text however the content will be dynamic so I don't think creating new line manually is a great option.
[image]

Here is my code so far. I can display text in one line.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { TextGeometry } from "three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry";
import { FontLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader";
import { ThreeJSOverlayView } from "@googlemaps/three";

const Text = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.map.setCenter(props.mapOptions.center);
    const overlay = new ThreeJSOverlayView({
      anchor: {
        lat: props.mapOptions.center.lat,
        lng: props.mapOptions.center.lng,
        altitude: 0,
      },
      upAxis: "Y",
    });
    overlay.setMap(props.map);

    const fontLoader = new FontLoader();

    fontLoader.load("./font.json", function (font) {
      const title = "HYATT HOTEL VANCOUVER";

      const geometry = new TextGeometry(title, {
        font: font,
        size: 60,
        height: 5,
      });

      const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x4285f4,
        specular: 0xffffff,
      });

      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

      mesh.position.copy(
        overlay.latLngAltitudeToVector3({
          lat: props.mapOptions.center.lat,
          lng: props.mapOptions.center.lng,
        })
      );

      mesh.position.setY(130);
      mesh.scale.set(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
      mesh.rotation.y = -Math.PI;

      overlay.scene.add(mesh);
    });
  }, []);
};

export default Text;
```

My questions are:

1. How do I set the width of text so that lines will automatically break?
2. How do I center the 3D text?

Answer (score 0):

To center the text on the X coordinate you can use this:

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();

const xMid = - 0.5 * ( geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x );

titleGeom.translate( xMid, 0, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight after posting that answer, I found a much simpler solution.

```js
geometry.center();
```

If you came up with the right solution I would love to see it. I am trying to implement the exact same example as your screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

For text I using on lot of projects css3D part of three.js - https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/renderers/CSS3DRenderer. Because is easier to render text as HTML. You just need implement logic, to follow some 3D empty point with text. You can use css styles for formating. You can also apply transformations for divs same as for 3D object. (I using css3Drender for example on homepage - https://mandrake.tv/)

To follow 3D object you can use somethink like this

```
 update(): void {
    if (!this.paused && this.objectsToFollow.length > 0 && this.gameObject && this.camera) {
      const pos = this.gameObject.getWorldPosition(new Vector3())
      const vec = this.toXYCoords(pos, this.camera)
      this.objectsToFollow.forEach(e => {
        const size = e.element.getBoundingClientRect()
        switch (e.anchor) {
          case FollowObjectAnchor.center:
            e.element.style.top = vec.y - (size.height / 2) + "px"
            e.element.style.left = vec.x - (size.width / 2) + "px"
            break;
          case FollowObjectAnchor.top:
            e.element.style.top = vec.y - (size.height) + "px"
            e.element.style.left = vec.x - (size.width / 2) + "px"
            break;
          case FollowObjectAnchor.bottom:
            e.element.style.top = vec.y + "px"
            e.element.style.left = vec.x - (size.width / 2) + "px"
            break;
          case FollowObjectAnchor.left:
            e.element.style.top = vec.y - (size.height / 2) + "px"
            e.element.style.left = vec.x - (size.width) + "px"
            break;
          case FollowObjectAnchor.right:
            e.element.style.top = vec.y - (size.height / 2) + "px"
            e.element.style.left = vec.x + "px"
            break;
        }
      })
    }
  }

  private toXYCoords(pos: Vector3, camera: Camera): Vector3 {
    const vector = pos.project(camera);
    const canvas = RenderManager.instance.renderer.domElement
    vector.x = (vector.x + 1) / 2 * canvas.clientWidth;
    vector.y = -(vector.y - 1) / 2 * canvas.clientHeight;
    return vector;
  }
```

ObjectsToFollow are 3D objects, which div should follow. But you can apply transformation directly to HTML object.